# Angular / .net core 3.1 Get Role Claim from JWT

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

i have this Claims inside my token but Role Claim its a URL Like this

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role
```

how can i get the value of role from this URL(in blue) in TypeScript

[image]

Comment: please show your token or Json object  instead of the screen shot

Comment: this is my object..how can i get the value of Role?

Comment: var role = myobject["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your claims are in a Json object you can use this syntax:

```
var role = myobject["schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"];
```